# why swagger is not working if i use the json to gson mapper property in application.properties

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

We are using spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson property in Spring boot application.properties to convert from json to gson for Junit test case. Not sure what is causing this property for swagger.

Getting fetching error when integrated with swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is an "old" post you might have had an answer still. What spring-boot do it's note magic. Based on your application configuration (dependencies class, files and so on) it will try to auto-configure your application.

**So by default you have this spring configuration**

```
# HTTP (HttpProperties)
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper= # Preferred JSON mapper to use for HTTP message conversion. By default, auto-detected according to the environment.
```

**To enable gson you have to include GSON dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This will allow spring-boot to detect **Gson** dependency on your classpath.

**Set thatjson mapper to gson:**

```
# Preferred JSON mapper to use for HTTP message conversion.
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
```

Configure Gson in spring boot

```
# GSON ([GsonProperties][1])
spring.gson.date-format= # Format to use when serializing Date objects.
spring.gson.disable-html-escaping= # Whether to disable the escaping of HTML characters such as '<', '>', etc.
spring.gson.disable-inner-class-serialization= # Whether to exclude inner classes during serialization.
spring.gson.enable-complex-map-key-serialization= # Whether to enable serialization of complex map keys (i.e. non-primitives).
spring.gson.exclude-fields-without-expose-annotation= # Whether to exclude all fields from consideration for serialization or deserialization that do not have the "Expose" annotation.
spring.gson.field-naming-policy= # Naming policy that should be applied to an object's field during serialization and deserialization.
spring.gson.generate-non-executable-json= # Whether to generate non executable JSON by prefixing the output with some special text.
spring.gson.lenient= # Whether to be lenient about parsing JSON that doesn't conform to RFC 4627.
spring.gson.long-serialization-policy= # Serialization policy for Long and long types.
spring.gson.pretty-printing= # Whether to output serialized JSON that fits in a page for pretty printing.
spring.gson.serialize-nulls= # Whether to serialize null fields.
```

You can also completely exclude jackson on your project doing do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <!-- Exclude the default Jackson dependency -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```